# Problems printing a session in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem while passing information with `$_SESSION` in php. Every time that I try it, it sends me a message saying "Array to string conversion".
Here is the code:

```
<?php

session_start(); 
ob_start();
include("conexion3.php");
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw) or die("Error");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("Error DB");

$sel2 = mysql_query("SELECT usuario_n,correo FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_n='machan'",$con);
$sesion = mysql_fetch_array($sel2);

$_SESSION['resultado'] = $sesion;

echo $_SESSION['resultado'];

?>
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use instead mysqli or PDO.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Maybe `$_SESSION['resultado']` contains an array that needs to be handled specially? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to echo out an array. $session stores the array you fetched from your mysql db. Try the following instead of that echo statement:

> print_r($_SESSION['resultado']);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in your last comment. The problem is, `$_SESSION['resultado']` is an array and with `echo $_SESSION['resultado'];` you're trying to convert array to string, hence the message.

You can do something like this to get the values:

```
echo $_SESSION['resultado'][0]; // machan
echo $_SESSION['resultado']['usuario_n']; // machan
echo $_SESSION['resultado'][1]; // elver@gmail.com
echo $_SESSION['resultado']['correo']; // elver@gmail.com
```

**Sidenote:** Please don't use the `mysql_` database extensions, they were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and were removed in PHP 7.0.0. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions instead. And this is [why you shouldn't use mysql_ functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).